# regex how to find two or more indentical lines with one line between in a file

Tags: regex, lines

i have some files and must find identical lines starting with "abc" and exact one line between these two identical lines.

```
lorem
abcdefg
lorem
abcdefg
lorem
lorem
abcdefg
abcdefg
lorem
lorem
```

in this sample the lines 2 and 4 should match but not then lines 4 and 7 and not the lines 7 and 8. is it possible?

Comment: What environment ? What have you done so far? Have you read what makes a [mcve]?

Comment: now i have read it :-) environment is windows and findstr

Comment: Appreciate you time reading it. Now please post your effort as some code in question. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Since you don't say the language I would do something like:

```
abc([^\n]+)\n[^\n]*\nabc(\1)
```

which checks for:

- Letters **abc**.
- a captured group without new lines.
- The new line character.
- A complete new line.
- The new line character.
- The previously matched first group content.

Check if its available for your language:
http://www.regular-expressions.info/refext.html (for instance in .NET this is not valid).

Comment: Why not just `abc([^\n]+)\n[^\n]*\nabc(\1)`.  That *will* work in .NET and, presumably, most, if not all, regex flavors.

Comment: i try it with this "(abc.*\n.*\nabc.*) /g" in regex101 and there it works.

Comment: i need it in windows findstr or in the "search and replace" program but there i got no match.

Comment: You are right @StevenDoggart . I'm gonna change it for your answer, way simpler. I did it like that because its a group match and I wrongly had in mind that \1 its only for replacements :p

Comment: About your answer @gsxr13000 that is not correct. Your regex accepts more than one line and doesn't match for the same text after the abc.